# Find the points where $f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Question: Let $f(x)$ be the function defined on the interval $(0,1)$ by $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}x(1-x)\hspace{1.4 cm}\text{if $x$ is rational,}\\\frac{1}{4}-x(1-x)\hspace{0.5 cm}\text{if $x$ is not rational.}\end{array}\right.$$ Then find the points where $f$ is continuous.

My approach: Select any rational point $a\in(0,1)$. We know that $\exists$ a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ of rational numbers such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$$ and $\exists$ a sequence $\{b_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ of irrational numbers such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=a.$$

Now if $f$ is continuous at $a$, then we must have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(b_n)=f(a)\\\iff \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n(1-a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{4}-b_n(1-b_n)=a(1-a)\\\iff a(1-a)=\frac{1}{4}-a(1-a)\\\iff 2a^2-2a+\frac{1}{4}=0\\\iff a=\frac{2\pm\sqrt 2}{4}.$$ But we have assumed $a$ to be rational so, $a\neq \frac{2\pm\sqrt 2}{4}$. Thus a contradiction is obtained. Thus $f$ is not continuous at any $a\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Now select any irrational point $b\in(0,1)$. Again, we know that $\exists$ a sequence $\{c_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ of rational numbers such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=b$$ and $\exists$ a sequence $\{d_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ of irrational numbers such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n=b.$$

Now if $f$ is continuous at $b$, then we must have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(c_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(d_n)=f(b)\\\iff \lim_{n\to\infty}c_n(1-c_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{4}-d_n(1-d_n)=\frac{1}{4}-b(1-b)\\\iff b(1-b)=\frac{1}{4}-b(1-b)\\\iff 2b^2-2b+\frac{1}{4}=0\\\iff b=\frac{2\pm\sqrt 2}{4}.$$

Thus if $f$ is continuous at some point $x\in(0,1)$, then $x=\frac{2\pm\sqrt 2}{4}.$

Now do we need to prove that the converse holds true, that is if $x=\frac{2\pm\sqrt 2}{4}$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$ to make the proof correct?

Comment: In the neighborhood of any point there will be infinite rationals and irrationals.

Comment: Yes you need to show continuity of $f$ at $a=1-\sqrt {2}/2$ in order to complete the proof.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, I have attached a partial proof below. Can you kindly help me to complete the proof. Also I made a calculation mistake, sorry for that. $x=\frac{2\pm\sqrt 2}{4}$ and not $1-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten this by  considering $any$ $a\in (0,1).$ The 1st part of your argument shows that IF $f$ is continuous at $a$ THEN $a\in \{(2\pm \sqrt 2)/4\}.$

Now the functions $g(x)=x(1-x)$ and $h(x)=1/4-g(x)$ are continuous at all $x\in (0,1)$. And $a\in \{(2\pm \sqrt 2)/4\}\implies g(a)=h(a).$ So IF $a\in \{(2\pm \sqrt 2)/4\}$ THEN $f$ is continuous at $a.$

Comment: @user26857. Suppose $f(a)=g(a)=h(a)$. Given any $e>0$, take $d,d'>0$ where $|x-a|<d\implies |g(x)-g(a)|<e$ and $|x-a|<d'\implies |h(x)-h(a)|<e.$ Let $d''=\min(d,d').$ Now if $|x-a|<d'' $ then $f(a)-e= \min(g(a)-e,h(a)-e))<$ $<\min(g(x),h(x))\le f(x)\le$ $\max(g(x),h(x))<$ $<\max (g(a)+e,h(a)+e)=f(a)+e,$ ... so $|f(x)-f(a)|<e.$

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this is not a complete answer and I would like to complete it with some help.

Let us take any sequence $\{s_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ of real numbers such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\frac{2+\sqrt 2}{4}.$$

Also define $\{q_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ to be any arbitrary subsequence of $\{s_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ such that it comprises of only rational numbers, $\{r_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ to be any arbitrary subsequence of $\{s_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ such that it comprises of only irrational numbers and finally $\{t_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ to be any arbitrary subsequence of $\{s_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ such that it comprises of both rational and irrational numbers.

Now we know that a sequence $\{k_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is convergent and converges to $k$ if and only if all of its subsequences are convergent and converges to $k$. $(*)$

Thus using $(*)$ we can conclude that, since $\{s_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is convergent and converges to $\frac{2+\sqrt 2}{4}$, thus we can conclude that both $\{q_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ and $\{r_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ are convergent sequences and their limit is $\frac{2+\sqrt 2}{4}$.

Now in order to prove that $f$ is continuous at $x=\frac{2+\sqrt 2}{4}$, it is both necessary and sufficient to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(s_n)=f\left(\frac{2+\sqrt 2}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{8}\hspace{0.5cm}(**).$$

Now to prove that $(**)$ holds true it is again necessary and sufficient to prove that any subsequence of $\{f(s_n)\}_{n\ge 1}$ is convergent and converges to $\frac{2+\sqrt 2}{4}$.

Now since $\{q_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ and $\{r_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ are convergent sequences, implies both the sequences $\{f(q_n)\}_{n\ge 1}$ and $\{f(r_n)\}_{n\ge 1}$ are convergent and we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(q_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n(1-q_n)=\frac{1}{8}$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(r_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{4}-r_n(1-r_n)\right)=\frac{1}{8}.$$

Thus if we can prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(t_n)=\frac{1}{8},$$ we will be done.

How to prove the same?

Also a similar analysis for $x=\frac{2-\sqrt 2}{4}$ will help us in proving that $f$ is continuous at $x=\frac{2-\sqrt 2}{4}.$

Hence, we will be able to conclude that $f$ is continuous only at $x=\frac{2\pm \sqrt2}{4}$. Observe that we can prove by contradiction that $f$ is not continuous at all other points.

Comment: It appears as if your thinking is correct but you have not been able to express it clearly. The sequential criteria of continuity is more useful in proving discontinuity rather than continuity. It is better to use the definition of continuity directly. The problem with your approach is that $s_n$ may not have the desired subsequences consisting of only rationals or only irrationals.

Comment: Let $g(x) =x(1-x)$ and $h(x) =(1/4)-g(x)$ then $g, h$ are continuous everywhere. In particular they are continuous at $a=(2+\sqrt{2})/4$. Hence for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta_1>0$ and a $\delta _2>0$ such that $|g(x) - g(a) |<\epsilon $ when $|x-a|<\delta_1$ and $|h(x) - h(a) |<\epsilon$ when $|x-a|<\delta_2$. Let $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$. Then it follows in obvious manner that $|f(x) - f(a) |<\epsilon $ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$. I hope you understand why this is obvious.